# Wait for data loaded before presenting or pushing ViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, closures, appdelegate, today-extension

I have today extension widget attached to my app. When user taps on widget I want to open my app's main ViewController called listVC (that is inside NavigationController) and after data is loaded from server push to detailed ViewController.

For handling app opening from widget I use this method from AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    if url.scheme == "MY_URL_SCHEME" { 
       .....
       return true
    }
}
```

To present data in detailed ViewController I need to wait until listVC will load it. What is the best way of solving it?

I thought about using some closure that will be set inside application method above and inside listVC data loading func this closure will executed after data was loaded.

Comment: You can show the view controller with a Heads Up Display, saying fetching data from server and hide it when you have the data.

Comment: Why wait for entire list view to be loaded, I suggest you get the api for the detail controller data and load the detailVC directly and call the api then, you can show an activity indicator for it.

Comment: @Geet, I don't have separate API for detailed view controller and I also have to load all feed - so data needed is already on device

Comment: Are you pushing detailVC manually? Or waiting for listVC's data and then pushing detailVC automatically? Then in that case what is use of showing listVC? Please elaborate your problem statement a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You could either have a login screen with an activity indicator where you load the data, or if listVC is a table you could connect the table to an array for the data, and when the data is loaded just reload the table and it will populate.

Comment: you didn't got the problem - i know how to present table view when data is loaded. I am asking about setting closure from AppDelegate